# Left stick on PlayStation 4 controller making me walk backwards

Tags: ps4, controllers

My PlayStation 4 controller makes me walk backwards when I point the left stick up. I tried watching a video and they advised that I clean it. After doing this the issue still occurs. The controller is also fairly new, it came with the ps4 I got a year ago. Any help will do.

Comment: Is this in all games or just in 1 game?

Comment: All games, modern warfare, Minecraft, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, there's a setting to invert controls:

> Option Button > Controller Layout > Controls > Controller, Inverted Y-Axis.

I don't have a PS, so I can't verify this information.

Answer (score 1):

If you have controller issues that aren't solved through a physical cleaning or mucking about in the options menu, you might have to do a soft or hard reset. Source: https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-reset-ps4-controller-4174025

## Soft reset (WARNING: YOU NEED A SECOND CONTROLLER FOR THIS):

1. Log in with your second (working) controller and navigate to the
   Settings in the PS4's top menu. This is the option that looks like a
   suitcase.
2. Choose Devices from the drop-down menu.
3. Select Bluetooth Devices. The settings for pairing your PS4 controller are under Bluetooth Devices, not Controllers.​
4. You should see your PS4 controller listed. Because we are using the
   working controller to navigate the menu, select the inactive one.
5. The PS4 controller with a green dot is the active controller and the
   PS4 controller without the green dot is the inactive one.
6. Press the Options button on your controller, found to the right of
   the touchpad. This will bring up a new menu.
7. Select Forget Device.
8. Now that we've forgotten the malfunctioning DualShock 4 controller,
   we want to power down the PS4. You can do this by holding down the
   PS4 button on your controller, navigating to Power in the menu and
   choosing Turn off PS4.
9. Connect your misbehaving DualShock 4 controller to the PS4 using a
   USB cable.
10. Turn on the PS4 and wait for it to boot up.
11. Press the PlayStation button on the controller and login to the
    PS4. The PlayStation 4 controller should now be paired and you can
    test to see if it's still misbehaving.

## Hard reset:

1. Power down the PS4.
2. Turn over the DualShock 4 controller and locate the small hole near
   the left shoulder button.
3. Unfold one end of the paper clip and insert it to push the button buried inside the hole.
4. Hold down this button for about 5 seconds.
5. Connect the controller to the PS4 using a USB cable.
6. Turn on the PS4 and wait for it to boot up.
7. Press the PlayStation button on the controller to log into the
   PS4. The light bar should turn blue indicating the DualShock 4 has
   paired with the console.